# How to print an image field on all the basic pages only?

Tags: theming, media

In my custom type "**Page**" I've added an image field (field_page_cover_image) and applied image style to it.

```
<?php
  $field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_page_cover_image');
  if($field){
     $theme_img = file_create_url($node->field_page_cover_image[$node->language][0]['uri']); //origional image path
     if(isset($theme_img)) {
        // print styled image
        print theme('image_style', array('path' => $node->field_page_cover_image[$node->language][0]['uri'], 'style_name' => 'page_theme'));
    }
  }  
?>
```

I have a requirement show this image (if uploaded) in all basic pages only (in a separate div container). For this I added the above code in `page.tpl.php

This code is working fine in all the pages but when I load search or other pages, I am getting error, as they don't have this field ($field).

Comment: Suresh there can be a relative easy approach for what you are trying to achieve, can you please add one more line in question about what exactly you want , in terms of functionality not in terms of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1 : use node.tpl.php

You should use a template for your specific content type "Page" instead of using page.tpl.php.

So try to copy paste the node.tpl.php, put your code in it, rename it node--page.tpl.php and upload it inside your theme folder.
Then it should only apply to content type "Page", and not all pages.

## Solution 2 : check that you're on a content type "Page" in page.tpl.php

If you need to put your code inside page.tpl.php, then you can check if you're viewing a content type "Page" this way:

```
$nid = arg(1);
$path = arg(0);
if(isset($nid) && is_numeric($nid) && isset($path) && $path == 'node') {
    $node = node_load($nid);
    if(isset($node) && $node->type == 'page') {
        // PUT YOUR CODE HERE
        ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Matt, the place where I want to show image is not into node.tpl.php. It is somewhere in header portion. So, I can't use node template :(

Comment: So you can try the second solution :)

Comment: <?php   if ($node->type == 'page') {}  ?>
I added this condition to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) and save your image to a variable. You can refer the below code.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
     $node = $vars['node'];
     $field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_page_cover_image');
      if($field){
         $theme_img = file_create_url($node->field_page_cover_image[$node->language][0]['uri']); //origional image path
         if(isset($theme_img)) {
            //print styled image
            $imagevariable = theme('image_style', array('path' => $node->field_page_cover_image[$node->language][0]['uri'], 'style_name' => 'page_theme'));
           $vars['myImage'] = $imagevariable;
        }
      }  
}
```

You can use **$myImage** variable to print the image in the tpl file :)

Comment: You can't always assume that a node is available in a `preprocess_page`, this will throw warnings ... (try on a user page)

Comment: @MikeVranckx , yes you right, I write this to take clue to him. the main idea is prepare variable that can use every where.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. The problem is with $field there is something wrong in that line. I am getting error in search, user and other pages, if I use it.